# Do I need to have a separate federated credential for every repo to use for GitHub actions?

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-aks

I have been trying to use GitHub actions to deploy to AKS, where it asks for a federated credential when logging in using service principal.

But while creating a federated credential, I can select only one GitHub Repo, and does that mean, for every deployment I have to create a new federated credential?